# Calling functions from header files

Tags: c++, scope

**Homework** 
I'm trying to call two functions in my main function from each of my three header files.

```
#ifndef UNSORTEDPQ_H
#define UNSORTEDPQ_H

#include <exception>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

template <class Type>
class UnsortedPQ
{
private:
struct DLLNode {
    Type data;
    DLLNode *prev;
    DLLNode *next;
};

DLLNode *head, *tail, *node;

public:
void insertUPQ ( Type data ){
  DLLNode *newnode = new DLLNode;
  newnode -> node = data;
  newnode -> prev = NULL;
  if (isEmpty()){
      newnode -> next = NULL;
      head = tail = newnode;
  } 
  else {
      newnode -> next = NULL;
      newnode -> prev = node -> prev -> next;
      tail = newnode;
  }
 }

 // removes and returns the minimum value in the queue
 // throws an exception if the queue is empty
 Type removeUPQ ( void ) throw(exception){
  if (isEmpty()) {
      exception("Can't dequeue empty Priority Queue");
  }

  Type min = head -> data;

  // special case: queue has one element
  if (size()==1){
      while (head != NULL) {
          DLLNode *next = head -> next;
          delete head;
          head = next;
      }
      return min;
  }

  // determine minimum element
  for (node = head; node != NULL; node = node -> next){
      if (node -> data < min) {
          min = node -> data;
      }
  }
  // special case: queue has two elements
  if (size()==2){
      if (head -> data== min){
          delete head;
          tail -> previous = NULL;
          head = tail;
      } 
      else {
          delete tail;
          head -> next = NULL;
          tail = head;
      }
      return min;
  }

  // remove element and update next and previous for elements around it
  for (node = head; node != NULL; node = node -> next){
      if (node -> data == min){
          // special case if min elem is head
          if (node == head){
              DLLNode*oldHead=head;
              head = head -> next;
              head -> prev = NULL;
              delete oldHead;
              return min;
          }
          // special case if min elem is tail
          if(node == tail){
              DLLNode*oldTail=tail;
              tail = tail-> prev;
              tail -> next = NULL;
              delete oldTail;
              return min;
          }
          // for cases where min elem is not head or tail
          DLLNode *prevNode = node -> prev;
          DLLNode *nextNode = node -> next;
          prevNode -> next = node -> next;
          nextNode -> prev = node -> prev;
          delete node;
          return min;
      }
}
```

---

```
#ifndef SORTEDPQ_H
#define SORTEDPQ_H

#include <exception>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

template <class Type>
class SortedPQ
{
private:
    struct DLLNode {
        Type data;
        DLLNode *prev;
        DLLNode *next;
    };

    DLLNode *head, *tail, *node;


public:

// inserts a piece of data into the priority queue
void insertSPQ ( Type data ){
DLLNode curr = head;
while(curr != tail && node -> data <= curr -> data){
    curr = curr -> next;
}
DLLNode tempCurr = curr;
node -> next = tempCurr;
node -> prev = tempCurr -> prev;
tempCurr -> prev -> next = node;
tempCurr -> prev = node;
}
// removes and returns the minimum value in the queue
// throws an exception if the queue is empty
Type removeSPQ ( void ) throw(exception){
 if (isEmpty()) {
    exception("Can't dequeue an empty Priority Queue");
}
Type min = head -> node;
if (node == head){
    DLLNode*oldHead=head;
    head = head -> next;
    head -> prev = NULL;
    delete oldHead;
    return min;
}
```

---

```
#ifndef HEAPPQ_H
#define HEAPPQ_H

#include <exception>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

template <class Type>
class HeapPQ
{
private:
    Type *data;
    Type heapSize;
    Type arraySize;
    Type floor(Type arg);
    Type getLChildIndex(Type nodeIndex){
        return 2 * nodeIndex + 1;
    } 

    Type getRightChildIndex(Type nodeIndex){
        return 2 * nodeIndex + 2;
    }

    Type getParentIndex(Type nodeIndex){
        return floor((nodeIndex - 1) / 2);
    }

    public:   
    void HeapPropertyInsert(Type nodeIndex){
    Type parentIndex, tmp;
    if(nodeIndex != 0){
        parentIndex = getParentIndex(nodeIndex);
        if(data[parentIndex] > data[nodeIndex]){
            tmp = data[parentIndex];
        data[parentIndex] = data[nodeIndex];
        data[nodeIndex] = tmp;
        HeapPropertyInsert(parentIndex);
        }
    }
   }

   // inserts a piece of data into the priority queue
   void insertHPQ ( Type data ) throw(exception){
    if (heapSize == arraySize){
        exception ("Cannot insert, heap is full");
    }
    else{
        heapSize++;
        data[heapSize - 1] = data;
        HeapPropertyInsert(heapSize - 1);
    }
   }

   void HeapPropertyRemove(Type nodeIndex){
    Type leftChildIndex, rightChildIndex, minIndex, tmp;
    leftChildIndex = getLChildIndex(nodeIndex);
    rightChildIndex = getRightChildIndex(nodeIndex);
    if(rightChildIndex >= heapSize){
        if(leftChildIndex >= heapSize)
            return;
        else
            minIndex = leftChildIndex;
    }
    else{
        if (data[leftChildIndex] < data[rightChildIndex])
            minIndex = leftChildIndex;
        else
            minIndex = rightChildIndex;
    }
    if(data[nodeIndex] > data[minIndex]){
        tmp = data[minIndex];
        data[minIndex] = data[nodeIndex];
        data[nodeIndex] = tmp;
        HeapPropertyRemove(minIndex);
    }
   }

   // removes and returns the minimum value in the queue
   // throws an exception if the queue is empty
   Type removeHPQ ( void ) throw(exception){
    if(isEmpty())
        exception("Cannot remove, heap is empty");
    else{
        data[0] = data[heapSize - 1];
        heapSize--;
        if(heapSize > 0)
            HeapPropertyRemove(0);
    }
   }
```

My main.cpp:

```
#include "UnsortedPQ.h"
#include "SortedPQ.h"
#include "HeapPQ.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int main(){

int choice;
int elem;
int array_size = 1024;
char * array = new char[array_size];
int position = 0;

ifstream fin("numbers.txt");
if(fin.is_open()){
    cout << "File opened successfully." << endl;
    while(!fin.eof() && position < array_size){
        fin.get(array[position]);
        position++;
    }
    array[0] = choice;
    switch (choice){
        case '0': //UnsortedPQ
            for(int i = 2; array[i]; i++ ){
                insertUPQ(array[i]); <----- error
                removeUPQ(array[i]); <----- error
            }
            break;
        case '1': //SortedPQ    
            for(int i = 2; array[i]; i++ ){
                insertSPQ(array[i]); <----- error
                removeSPQ(array[i]); <----- error
            }
            break;
        case '2':// HeapPQ  
            for(int i = 2; array[i]; i++ ){
                insertHPQ(array[i]); <----- error
                removeHPQ(array[i]); <----- error
            }
            break;
    }
}
else{
    cout << "File could not be opened." << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

I keep receiving compiler errors stating that these functions "are not declared in this scope". I thought that since the header files were included and the functions are public, that I could call them at will anywhere in the main.cpp. Again, this is **homework**, so I'm not looking for a quick fix, but some advice or a point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are missing `#endif` at the end of all of your header files.

Comment: Owww... Too much source here. We're not solving homeworks.

Comment: `insertSPQ`, for example, is inside the `SortedPQ` class. It's a method. That means you can only call it on instances of the class. And you seem to have a random `public:` elsewhere outside of a class declaration (it's only valid within a class/struct).

Answer (score 2):

All the **functions** you are trying to call are **methods** that belong to the specific **class**. In order to use these **method** you have to create an **object** of a specific **class**:

```
char * array = new char[array_size];

UnsortedPQ<char> Object;

Object.insertUPQ(array[i]);
```

There is a link to the tutorial that explains what exactly are classes in C++, how to create them and use them:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Comment: Wouldn't I have to use `<Type>` since my classes are templated?

Comment: You mean on each method call? No. You tell the compiler with what class your class is compiled when declaring an object of a templated class: `UnsortedPQ<char> Object;` In this situation `<Type>` is `<char>` and all methods and variables in the class are compiled as chars. This way you can create a class that can work with many data types and even with other classes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues with this code.  Without even going into possible problem with the individual function implementations, the following errors need to be fixed:

1. You can't call a class method without having an instance of that class.  So, to call the method `insertSPQ`, you have to have `SortedPQ` class.  You can create one like this:

`SortedPQ<char> *spq = new SortedPQ<char>;`

Then call the function like this:

`spq->insertSPQ(array[i]);`

---

2. You are calling functions using an incorrect signature.  For example, you try to call

`spq->removeSPQ(array[i]);`

(after I added the spq class instance ), but the arguments for that function are defined as void as shown below:

`Type removeSPQ(void) throw(exception){`

So your sorted if condition should look more like:

```
    case '1': //SortedPQ    
        SortedPQ<char> *spq = new SortedPQ<char>;

        for (int i = 2; array[i]; i++){
            spq->insertSPQ(array[i]);
            spq->removeSPQ(array[i]);
        }
        break;
```

---

Of course, that doesn't really fix everything, because you still need to free the memory from spq.

Additonally, as another commenter pointed out, you are missing `#endif` 's.  Those should be the last line of each header file to close your initial `#ifndef` 's.

Finally, it's usually considered a bad practice to have your class implementation and declaration in the same header file.  It's generally better to have a .h file for the declaration and a separate .cpp for the actual implementation.  It should WORK as is, just not a best practice.